# jQuery REGEX add automatically space

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-ui, regexp-replace

I may have a little stupid question, but I am wondering how to make field to have space after two characters, and after that to have space after every 3 characters, for example:

**99 999 999 999**

I used this code:

```
  $('#form-field-indentification_number').keyup(function() {
      
  var indent = $(this).val().split(" ").join(""); // remove hyphens

  if (indent.length > 2 && indent.length < 4 ) {
    indent = indent.match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join(" ");
  }
  
  if (indent.length > 5 ) {
    indent = indent.match(new RegExp('.{1,3}', 'g')).join(" ");
  }
  
  $(this).val(indent);
```

But still can't handle it :(

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand that you have a string of contiguous digits like 99999999999 and you would like to insert space every third group from the right.

You can accomplish that with a regex replace where you search with

```
(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(\D|$))
```

and replace with `$1` .

The first part of the regex, `(\d{1,3})`, captures one to three digits into group 1.  The rest is a lookahead whose first part, `(?=(\d{3})+` forms one or more groups of exactly 3 digits and whose last part `(\D|$))` anchors the scan to the rightmost part of the digits.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, could you help to use this in jQuery string, txt replace is not working in this case

Comment: @Vladimir, Should be `indent.replace('/(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(\D|$))/g', '$1 ')`.